# Download speed jumping around allover

Tags: c++, winapi, libcurl

I have a little program that downloads files from ftp using curl. And in the function passed in CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, I do calculations to know the download speed, the problem is the download speed jumps all over the place, from 512kbps to 8mbps on a 2mbps internet connection. And I couldn't determine what's wrong here.

**EDIT :** I have changed the code to average out the readings, the problem with curl download is you can not predict when the TraceProgress function will be called, it can be called again in less then 1 second, so program waits for 5 iterations to note down the readings, and take 6 such readings before averaging, I have also considered time(seconds) elapsed since last reading was taken, since we can not guarantee that TraceProgress function will be called at equal intervals.

Let me know if it looks better now.

Here is the code :

```
int minorCounter = 0;
int majorCounter = 0;

int minorCycle = 4;
int majorCycle = 5;

double blockDL[6];
double blockTime[6];

int TraceProgress( void *clientp, double dltotal, double dlnow, double ultotal, double ulnow )
{

  if ( minorCounter == minorCycle )
    {

            blockDL[majorCounter] = dlnow - oldDownloadNow;

            myTimer.Tick();
            blockTime[majorCounter] = myTimer.GetDurationInSecs();

            minorCounter = 0;


            if ( majorCounter == majorCycle )
            {
                double dl = 0;
                double tm = 0;

                for ( int i = 0; i < majorCycle ; i++ )
                {
                    dl += blockDL[i];
                    tm += blockTime[i];
                }

                dl = dl/(majorCycle+1);

                tm = tm/(majorCycle+1);

                double currentDownloadSpeed = dl / tm;

                /* download speed - divide by 1024 to get speed in kilobytes instead of bytes */
                double idownloadSpeed = currentDownloadSpeed / 1024;

                string post;
                if ( idownloadSpeed > 1024 )
                {
                       idownloadSpeed = idownloadSpeed / 1024;
                       post = " MB/s";
                }
                else
                {
                        post = " KB/s";
                }

                string downloadSpeed = DoubleToString( idownloadSpeed );

                size_t x = downloadSpeed.find( "." );
                downloadSpeed.erase( x+2 );

                downSize = "Download Speed:  " + downloadSpeed + post;
                SendMessage( hDownloadSpeedSTATIC, WM_SETTEXT, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)downSize.c_str() );

                majorCounter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                majorCounter++;
            }

            oldDownloadNow = dlnow;
            myTimer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
            minorCounter++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably measuring over too short a period of time. I'd guess a moving average over, say, the last 30 seconds or so would smooth the variations and still show reasonably current data.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yeah, that was dumb of me to not understanding the scenario properly, I have changed the code above, what you think ?

Comment: Certainly looks quite a bit closer anyway. And yes, given the uneven rate at which your callback can be called, it is difficult to make things work well.

Comment: @JerryCoffin any input on how can I improve on it ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a sampling window and exponential decay or something else sane.

If a car comes off an assembly line every 30 minutes, and you just take a single sample, horrible things can happen. For example, if you sample just after a car comes off the line and then sample again 20 minutes later, you'll see zero cars in 20 minutes, a rate of zero cars per hour. If you sample just before a car comes off the line and again 31 minutes later, you'll see two cars in 31 minutes, a rate of 3.9 cars per hour.

Here's one simple algorithm:

1. Keep a single count and a single average speed. Start them both at zero.
2. Update each second.
3. Each second, first add to the count the number of **bytes** received in the previous second.
4. After adding the count, subtract 1/8th of the count from the count. `count -= (count/8);`
5. Update the smoothed average speed, in **bits**  per second, to be the current count. `bits_per_sec = count;`.

To see why this algorithm works, assume the count is constant. That means the amount added to the count must equal the amount subtracted. That means the count must be 8 times the number of bytes added each second, making it the number of bits per second received.

Comment: I have changed the code above, can you please have a look and let me know if it looks better ?

Comment: If you can't ensure your function is called at equal intervals, you can just track the last time you did the `count -= (count/8);`. If less than a second has passed, don't do it. If more than two seconds have passed, do it two times or more.